# Can more traffic be directed to CareerOverflow

Tags: feature-request, discussion

**Can more traffic be directed to CareerOverflow?**
Hi,

I've noticed questions being migrated from StackOverflow to the Programmers site, and now I'm hooked. Maybe you can migrate questions to CareerOverflow or advertise on other stackexchange sites.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CareerOverflow is a StackExchange 1.0 site, so it is not possible to migrate questions to it.